# index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas

Bom, estou com esse código, quero que ele pegue colunas especificas de 3 planilhas e junte numa só, ams está dando o seguinte erro: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

```
import pandas as pd


Corp = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/t718787/Desktop/fotos/dbm.xlsx', 'Corp', usecols =['Num_CNPJ','Segmento','Cliente','Grupo','Regional','Gestor_Senior','Gerente','Lista_Distribuicao'])

Scib = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/t718787/Desktop/fotos/dbm.xlsx', 'SCIB', usecols =['Num_CNPJ','Segmento','Cliente','Grupo','Regional','Gestor_Senior','Gerente','Lista_Distribuicao'])

Gi = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/t718787/Desktop/fotos/dbm.xlsx', 'GI', usecols =['Num_CNPJ','Segmento','Cliente','Grupo','Regional','Gestor_Senior','Gerente','Lista_Distribuicao'])

Univ = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/t718787/Desktop/fotos/dbm.xlsx', 'Univ', usecols =['Num_CNPJ','Segmento','Cliente','Grupo','Regional','Gestor_Senior','Gerente','Lista_Distribuicao'])


df = pd.DataFrame()

Corp ['Num_CNPJ'] = Corp['Num_CNPJ'].astype(str)

Corp ['Num_CNPJ'] = Corp ['Num_CNPJ'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>14}'.format(x))

Corp = df.insert(loc=0,column='Agencia_conta', value='--')
Corp = df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')
Corp = df.insert(loc=7,column='Telefone_gerente', value='--')



#config SCIB
Scib ['Num_CNPJ'] = Scib['CNPJ'].astype(str)

Scib ['Num_CNPJ'] = Scib['Num_CNPJ'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>14}'.format(x))

Scib = df.insert(loc=0,column='Agencia_conta', value='--')
Scib = df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')
Scib = df.insert(loc=7,column='Telefone_gerente', value='--')



#config GI

Gi['Num_CNPJ'] = Gi ['Num_CNPJ'].astype(str)

Gi['Num_CNPJ'] = Gi ['Num_CNPJ'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>14}'.format(x))

Gi = df.insert(loc=0,column='Agencia_conta', value='--')
Gi = df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')
Gi = df.insert(loc=7,column='Telefone_gerente', value='--')



#config UNIV

Univ ['Num_CNPJ'] = Univ ['Num_CNPJ'].astype(str)

Univ ['Num_CNPJ'] = Univ ['Num_CNPJ'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>14}'.format(x))

Univ = df.insert(loc=0,column='Agencia_conta', value='--')
Univ = df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')
Univ = df.insert(loc=7,column='Telefone_gerente', value='--')


df = df.append (Corp)
df = df.append (Scib)
df = df.append (Gi)
df = df.append (Univ)

df = df.iloc [:,[0,3,4,5,6,12,13,9,14,23,2]]


df.to_excel ('C:/Users/t718787/Desktop/fotos/DBM_prt.xlsx', index = False)
print(df.count())
```

Answer (score 1):

Construiria isso da seguinte forma:

1º Construiria uma lista com os nome das planilhas e iria ler esses dataframes e salvar em uma outra lista:

```
sheets = ['Corp', 'SCIB', 'GI', 'Univ']
dfs = list()

for name in sheets:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel('Untitled 1.xlsx', name, usecols =['Num_CNPJ','Segmento','Cliente','Grupo','Regional','Gestor_Senior','Gerente','Lista_Distribuicao']))
```

2º Iria concatenas em um dataframe só:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

3º Iria realizar as transformações e as criações de novas colunas:

```
df['Num_CNPJ'] = df['Num_CNPJ'].astype(str)
df['Num_CNPJ'] = df['Num_CNPJ'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>14}'.format(x))

df.insert(loc=0,column='Agencia_conta', value='--')
df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')
df.insert(loc=7,column='Telefone_gerente', value='--')
```

Comment: Juan, fiz como disse, criei a planilha e deu certo, vlw em, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que bom que essa ideia conseguiu lhe ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

O erro está aqui:

`Corp = df.insert(loc=5,column='Email_cliente', value='--')`

Você criou um dataframe novo chamado df que não tem nenhuma coluna ainda, então ele vai aceitar que vc criei colunas dentro do limite dele, ou seja primeiro vc cria a 0 depois a 1 depois a 2 e assim sucessivamente. Quando vc usa o `loc=5` sem ter uma coluna 1-2-3-4 criadas vc extrapola o limite.

O jeito teoricamente certo seria esse aqui:

`Corp = df.insert(loc=1,column='Email_cliente', value='--')`

Comment: AH, eu fiz isso pq, tbm estou pegando colunas de outras planilhas, já existentes, posso criar  na ordem 1 2 3... e dps arruma na ordem em df = df.iloc [:,[0,3,4,5,6,12,13,9,14,23,2]] ? , estou nisso a tarde toda

Comment: pode sim, se vc fizer assim teoricamente funciona!

Comment: então juan, fiz assim, mas em vez dele pegar das planilhas existentes ele, só copiou varias vezes o 0 1 2

Comment: Agora eu não entendo o porque vc atribui uma variável que é um dataframe um outro dataframe vazio?? Poderia explicar melhor qual o seu objetivo?? Se vc quer pegar varios dataframes e agregá-los em um dataframe só sugiro vc utilizar o concat, por último vc criaria essas outras colunas que vc quer.

Comment: eu estou tentando criar uma planilha nova, nela eu preciso de colunas que estão numa planilha já existentes, que já possuem valores e tbm criar colunas novas.

Comment: Coloquei uma outra reposta de como eu faria isso!